# Web App Error After Installing Java on Centos Server

Tags: centos, email, smtp, java, web-applications

Good day.

My web app is programmed in jsp, using some of jQuery and javascript, is on a server with Centos 6.4, the app run its own java 1.7.0 - tomcat 8.0.21 and between its functions, uses javax.mail library which in a normal day can send from 5 to 50 messages.

As the server does not have native java and i need to run some jars on it, i installed java 1.7.0 using yum install to the server that does not have any conflict with the app's java on the start and/or execution.

The app starts normally and almost everything is ok, but after the installation of the server's java, i got javax.mail.messagingexception[eof] when my app is trying to send a mail through gmail smtp.

My immediate idea was to remove the server's java using yum remove and reboot the system but, the issue persists.

I tried to update google's certificates, verify the config of smtp and the authentication from centos console but everything seems to be ok, even i am able to send a mail from the centos console without any error or exception, but not from the app.

i where searching for almost 2 weeks including every reference to the javax.mail exception and there is no clue why the java installation could produce the malfunction.

i have no more info or exception code because the app was programmed like this and i cannot access to the font-code, the app log only prints javax.mail.messagingexception[eof] .

Anyone knows how the java installation can produce this?

There is temp-files or something that could remains on centos after uninstall that can produce this?

Sorry for the length, i had to provide as much details as posible due to the nature and conditions of the situation.

Thanks for your time, regards.

Moved from [Web App Error After Installing - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454939/web-app-error-after-installing-java-on-centos-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED 12/04/2016 :** The issue was solved by tracing the EHLO hostname sent to gmail through smtp, which were incomplete so, the parameter was modified with the server's fullname. Thanks for your time.